# How do I make the contents of a flex layout fill the parent?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

So I am trying to create a flex layout where the children fill the vertical space of the parent.

I have attempted this here:  https://jsfiddle.net/3ryma0sn/50/

```
<body>
<div class="vLayout">
  <div class="hLayout">
    x
  </div>
  <div class="hLayout">
    x
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

```
.vLayout {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  gap: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  
}

.hLayout {
  background-color: #ffff00;
  margin: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

My expectation would be that because the parent is `align-items: stretch` and the children are `flex-grow: 1` that the children should stretch to fill the parent.  However instead the child divs only wrap their content:

[image]

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: Did you add height : 100vh; to children? if you got 2 you can use height : 50vh;

Comment: So I just tried it, and it's broken with the margins.  I.e. if I want to have the margins, then 50vh makes the yellow divs overflow the red div.  Is there a way to just make it fill the parent evenly?

Comment: you are missing display:flex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the display property on your `vLayout` class by adding: `display: flex;`

```css
.vLayout {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  gap: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.vLayout>* {
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.hLayout {
  background-color: #ffff00;
  margin: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="vLayout">
    <div class="hLayout">
      x
    </div>
    <div class="hLayout">
      x
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```